# this div to cover up the viewport works perfect on IE 7, 8, FF, Chrome, and Safari, but why not IE 6?

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

this div to cover up the viewport works perfect on IE 7, 8, FF, Chrome, and Safari, but why not IE 6?

http://www.0011.com/css/test/cover_up/i4.html

I thought IE 6 breaks if it is position: fixed but not absolute?

(on IE 6, the div is only 1 line tall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex's suggestion works 99%:

http://www.0011.com/css/test/cover_up/i4b.html

however,

1) scrollbar pops up when the cover div appears

2) how come the absolutely positioned div doesn't have a height of the viewport on IE 6?  I thought the spec says when there is no nearest ancestor that is "positioned", then the viewport is the containing element.  IE 6 doesn't follow the spec on this again?

Answer (score 0):

IE6 does not interpret object element height like other browsers, so you can't really use 'height=100%'.  Sadly, the only way I know of to address this issue is to use javascript to determine the width and height of the viewable window in pixels, then set 'min-width' and 'min-height' stylings to these values.

[This link](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/16/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/) should help you find what you're looking for.